# Why does naming a file 'con.txt' in windows make Python write to console, not file?

Tags: python

I need help debugging some odd file behavior in Python.  Take the following script (`write_con.py`):

```
f=open('con.txt','w')
f.write('hi')
```

In Linux, this creates a file called `con.txt` with the contents `hi`.  In Windows this writes `hi` to the console and does not create a file.  I've tried this with Python 2.5.1, 2.6.3, 2.6.5, and 2.7.2.  Example run:

```
C:\Users\rpsharp> C:\Python27\python.exe .\write_con.py
hiC:\Users\rpsharp> C:\Python25\python.exe .\write_con.py
hiC:\Users\rpsharp>
```

Yet a file named anything other than something that starts with `con` works fine (`write_other_con.py`):

```
f=open('other_con.txt','w')
f.write('hi')
```

Here's a run:

```
C:\Users\rpsharp> C:\Python25\python.exe .\write_other_con.py
C:\Users\rpsharp> type .\other_con.txt
hi
```

What's going on that causes windows versions of python to write to the console when the prefix of the named file is `con`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to check the [Wikipedia Filename page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename). It has a table containing the reserved characters for quite a lot of file systems.

*In Windows and DOS utilities, some words might also be reserved and can not be used as filenames. For example, DOS Device file:*

***CON**, PRN, AUX, CLOCK$, NUL
COM0, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9
LPT0, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9.*

Answer (score 11):

[Legacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words). In DOS, writing to a file called "CON" writes it to the console instead; Windows continues this tradition.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a Python error, but a Windows naming convention. There are a list of reserved keywords that Windows will not allow you to save files or folders as, including `CON, PRN, AUX, CLOCK$, NUL
COM0, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT0, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, LPT9.`

Answer (score 1):

In Windows  con is reserved word and can not be used as filename.