# cv2.imwrite opencv cannot save image with name con.jpg

Tags: python, opencv

This is a simple program to create an empty image and save it with name con.jpg.

```
import cv2
import numpy

img = numpy.zeros([500,500],numpy.uint8)
cv2.imwrite("con.jpg",img)
```

But the image is not getting saved with this name **con.jpg** whereas if I write the name anything else like a , con1, cont, etc its working fine.
Any answer for this weird behavior of `imwrite`.

Comment: What platform? Which version of OpenCV (not that it would make much difference given the cause)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does naming a file 'con.txt' in windows make Python write to console, not file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895686/why-does-naming-a-file-con-txt-in-windows-make-python-write-to-console-not-fi) -- i.e. You're trying to use a reserved word as a file name. That won't work.